# Get Site Permissions with PnP PowerShell

Tags: permissions, office-365, pnp-powershell

How can I retrieve site permissions on a site or subsite using PnP PowerShell?

Example: https://$orgName.sharepoint.com/sites/IT/Atlas

Via the UI: Site settings > Site Permissions

With PnP PowerShell, the following didn't work for me:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://$orgName.sharepoint.com/sites/IT/Atlas" -Credentials $userCredential
$web = Get-PnPWeb -Includes RoleAssignments
```

[Edit] The above code actually seems to work, as $web.RoleAssignments.Count returns 5. My issue is that I don't know how to take it from here, to enumerate the 5 members and their roles.

RoleAssignments.Member returns 5 items but I can't figure out how to get the names and roles.

RoleAssignments.Groups only returns the SharePoint groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question has been answered on [Microsoft Tech Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Developer/Get-Site-Permissions-with-PnP-PowerShell/m-p/141219#M305).

Here is the accepted answer:

```
$cred = get-credential
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://$orgname.sharepoint.com" -Credentials $cred
$web = Get-PnPWeb -Includes RoleAssignments
foreach($ra in $web.RoleAssignments) {
    $member = $ra.Member
    $loginName = get-pnpproperty -ClientObject $member -Property LoginName
    $rolebindings = get-pnpproperty -ClientObject $ra -Property RoleDefinitionBindings
    write-host "$($loginName) - $($rolebindings.Name)"
    write-host  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following PowerShell code snippet assits to retrieve the site properties:

$siteurl = "https://abc.sharepoint.com"
Connect-SPOnline -Url $siteurl
$ctx = Get-SPOContext

## Get Current Context Site (Root)

function RetrieveSite(){
    $web = Get-SPOWeb
    Write-Host "Title : " $web.Title
    Write-Host "Description : " $web.Description
    Write-Host "URL : " $web.Url
}

## Get Sub Site

function RetrieveSubSite(){
    $web = Get-SPOWeb "PnPSite1"
    Write-Host "Title : " $web.Title
    Write-Host "Description : " $web.Description
    Write-Host "URL : " $web.Url
}
RetrieveSite #Get Current Context Site (Root)
RetrieveSubSite #Get Sub Site

Please refer to the below link

[Use powershell to retrieve all subsites for sharepoint online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604076/use-powershell-to-retrieve-all-subsites-for-sharepoint-online)

Hope it helps!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question for how to retrieve the permissions for a site.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My question is specifically about fixing the code I posted (use of PnP), and retrieving site permissions. Everything else (title, description, URL) works as intended.